# .NET Core 2.1 CLI dotnet.exe and LibraryManager Set Proxy

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I have an ASP.NET Core application that uses Microsoft LibraryManager to pull client libraries jQuery (cdnjs) and BootStrap (unpkg) into the project.

I'm running into errors when trying to build the project with dotnet cli because my current proxy settings require authentication.  I'd like to force dotnet.exe, or LibraryManager to use a different proxy that doesn't require authentication.

I tried setting the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY Environment Variables but they had no impact.

Is there any way to configure the proxy that dotnet.exe or LibraryManager uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't had a chance to try this yet but the GitHub page for this issue was recently updated and states that the latest version of Library Manager now includes configuration options for setting a proxy URL as well as adding authentication.  Here's a link to the [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager/issues/399#issuecomment-491922954) on GitHub.